# In pokemon y can you mega evolve an Infernape?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I just recently transferred all of my pokemon from my old games and have my lv 100 Infernape on my Y game now and was wondering if I could mega evolve my Infernape or not, and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There is no [Mega Stone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mega_stone) for Infernape, and thus it cannot Mega evolve.